# Difference between timestamps in Javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I just want to confirm what I have, I saw on stackoverflow that I can get do the following:

```
var current_time = +new Date();
console.log (current_time);
var fetch_time = +new Date();
console.log((fetch_time-current_time));
```

and I now I just want to know what this difference is in. milliseconds?

```
Log Output
1375976707028
76
```

I just simply want the fastest way to check if 60 seconds have passed or not. I'd rather avoid any kind of operations like multiplication or division.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` looks a little weird there, I'd just use `.getTime()`.

`.getTime()` returns milliseconds, so compare with `60000`.

Comment: oh sorry it is confusing

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
var current_time = +new Date();
var fetch_time;
console.log (current_time);

setTimeout(function() {
    fetch_time = +new Date();
    console.log((fetch_time-current_time)); // 1000 -> ms, 1 -> s
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I will go with the .getTime and the 6000 check.